# How to pass "-Xlint:unchecked" java compiler option to maven, from command line?

Tags: maven, compilation, arguments, lint, checked

As described in the title, I tried this:

```
maven ..... -D exec.args=-Xlint:unchecked
```

But didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Simply use: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html (but in the pom file)...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks, but I just wish to know how to pass this param to maven command line?

Comment: Also please check https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html#environment-variables (I would recomment to configure that in your pom file) more concise and you get allways the same result...

Comment: No space - just `-Dexec…`